# replace character with increasing numbers per line

Tags: perl, awk, increment

I have large matrix files consisting of only "0" and "a" in clolumns and I want to do what this does:

```
perl -pe 'BEGIN { our $i = 1; } s/a/($i++)/ge;'; < FILE > NEW_FILE
```

but only increment once for each line instead of every instance on each line.

So if my first line in the file is:

```
0 0 a a a
```

The perl command gives me:

```
0 0 1 2 3
```

While i would want

```
0 0 1 1 1
```

and on the next line for instance `2 0 2 0 2` and so on...

This should be possible to do with awk, but using:

```
'{ i=1; gsub(/a/,(i+1));print}' tmp2
```

just gives me 0's and 2's for all lines...

Answer (score 5):

Just increment before, not on every substitution:

```
awk '{i++; gsub(/a/,i)}1' file
```

This way, the variable gets updated once per line, not once per record.

The same applies to the Perl script:

```
perl -pe 'BEGIN { our $i = 0; } $i++; s/a/$i/ge;' file
```

#### Test

```
$ cat a
0 0 a a a
2 3 a a a
$ awk '{i++; gsub(/a/,i)}1' a
0 0 1 1 1
2 3 2 2 2
$ perl -pe 'BEGIN { our $i = 0; } $i++; s/a/$i/ge;' a
0 0 1 1 1
2 3 2 2 2
```

Comment: You can just use `i` once `'{gsub(/a/,++i)}1'`

Answer (score 3):

You can simply replace every occurrence of `a` with the current line number

```
perl -pe 's/a/$./g' FILE > NEW_FILE
```

Answer (score 1):

```
perl -pe'$i++;s/a/$i/g'
```

or if you like to increment only for lines with any substitution

```
perl -pe'/a/&&$i++;s/a/$i/g'
```

In action:

```
$ cat a
0 0 a a a
1 2 0 0 0
2 3 a a a
$ perl -pe'$i++;s/a/$i/g' a
0 0 1 1 1
1 2 0 0 0
2 3 3 3 3
$ perl -pe'/a/&&$i++;s/a/$i/g' a
0 0 1 1 1
1 2 0 0 0
2 3 2 2 2
```